# "Required" attribute on a property of a Class in APEX?

Tags: apex, apexrest

I have a request class used to call into a REST endpoint for an APEX class.

I wish to mark a property on the class required so that I do not need to manually validate the field.

How is that done?

Something like this would be nice:

```
Public class MyRequest{
    [Required] String UserName;     
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no attribute to mark a particular field as required in apex.
Only annotations in apex rest are these : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation.htm

@ReadOnly 
@RestResource(urlMapping='/yourUrl') 
@HttpDelete 
@HttpGet 
@HttpPatch 
@HttpPost 
@HttpPut

Either you need to put the logic in the caller service, or if you want to put a logic in apex, then, you need to write the logic in Apex. Something like this.

Check required fields:

```
public static Boolean isRequestValid(MyRequest myRequest){
    return String.isNotBlank(myRequest.UserName);
}
```

And other params as required.